# Issue with SQL Server trigger event firing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a trigger on a table that is something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [shoot_sms] 
  ON  [dbo].[MyTable]
 AFTER  INSERT
AS
begin
declare @number bigint
declare @body varchar(50)
declare @flag int

select @number=number,@body=body,@flag=flag from inserted

if(@flag=0)
begin

insert into temptable (number,body,status)
select @number,@body,'P'

end
end
```

Now I am making two entries in mytable as below:

```
insert into mytable(number, body, flag)
values(3018440225, 'This is test', 0)

insert into mytable(number, body, flag)
values(3018440225, 'This is test', 0)
```

I execute these queries at a time, but for both of the queries the trigger fires only once and performs the task for the first query only.

How can I make it work for both insert statements?

Comment: So you mean while inserting two records to `mytable`, only one entry is populated in table `temptable `?

Comment: yes exactly. The first entry is populated always.

Comment: Is there any exception while inserting?

Comment: This *looks* like SQL Server (e.g. an `inserted` pseudo-table), so I've added that tag. If that's incorrect, please remove that tag and *add* a suitable tag for your RDBMS. Triggers are incredibly specific to their database systems.

Comment: no there isnt any exception while inserting.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea but put a GO statement between those two insert statements and that might cause the trigger to fire twice.

You should probably rewrite your trigger to handle multiple row inserts I think.

Here is your query converted. You should get two rows now.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [shoot_sms] 
  ON  [dbo].[MyTable]
 AFTER  INSERT
AS
begin


insert into temptable (number,body,status)
select number,body,'P'
from inserted
where flag = 0

end
```

Also notice your trigger is much simpler now.

Comment: actually the problem is this that the insert entries are to be made by an application. I cant do what you have suggested. There could by 5 6 or hundreds of entries simultaneously.

Comment: how can I write it to handle multiple rows?? can you please help?

Comment: I just updated the answer with the proper SQL for you to handle multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

Since those two statements are in one SQL batch, the trigger **will** (by design) only fire once.

Triggers **don't fire once per row** - they fire **once per statement**! So if you have an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement that affects more than one row, your trigger will have more than one row in the `Inserted` (and possibly `Deleted`) pseudo tables.

The way you wrote this trigger is really **not** taking into account that `Inserted` could contain multiple rows - what row do you select from the `Inserted` table if you're inserting 20 rows at once?

```
select @number = number, @body = body, @flag = flag from inserted
```

You need to change your trigger to take that into account!

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: once per statement would be correct - thanks for pointing that out!